# Codeigniter : upload path does not appear to be valid

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the following function in my model:

```
function uploadsinglepicture($uploadpath){

    $config['upload_path'] =$uploadpath;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '';
    $config['max_width']  = '';
    $config['max_height']  = '';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);
        if($this->input->post('id') == ''){
            $insertion['image'] = '';
        }
        //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $insertion['image'] = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
    }

    $image = $insertion['image'];
    return $image;
}
```

This is how I access the function in controller:

```
if(!empty($this->input->post())){
                $path= base_url().'assets/front/img';
                $this->general->uploadsinglepicture($path);
                redirect(base_url().'admin/home/index/sliderupated');
}
```

but the error I get is:

> Array ( [error] => The upload path does not appear to be valid.
>   )

If I print `$path`, this is what I get

```
http://localhost/site/assets/front/img/
```

and that opens in the browser as real path. My code in view is as below

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action ="<?=base_url()?>admin/home/index" >
    <label>Upload Picture </label>
    <input type='file'  name='userfile' />
    <input type="hidden" name="updateimage">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
</form>
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: You need to give absolute path to upload file

Comment: how do i do that please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please update this line,

```
from ,  $path= base_url().'assets/front/img'; 

to,     $path= FCPATH.'assets/front/img';
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving `base_url()` you need to give base  directory. So change your code to:

```
if(!empty($this->input->post())){
                $path= FCPATH.'assets/front/img';
                $this->general->uploadsinglepicture($path);
                redirect(base_url().'admin/home/index/sliderupated');
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `FCPATH` this :**

```
  $path= FCPATH.'assets/front/img';
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Answer (score 0):

**FCPATH:** front controller path where index.php exists or **root** folder

**APPPATH:** **application** folder

Create a **uploads** folder under **root** folder:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath(FCPATH.'uploads');
```

Create a **uploads** folder under **application** folder:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH.'uploads');
```

In case: If you have created the **uploads** folder outside of **root** folder:

```
$config['upload_path'] = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads');
```